# Is this an appropriate use of class friendship?

Tags: c++, oop, class, friend

When creating windows parent and child dialog classes, is it generally a good idea to make the child class a friend of parent class to access its private data or should you use accessor functions?

Comment: You make classes "friends" when you really want to touch their uhm ... privates. However, just as in real-life, this can lead to some rather complicated not-so-fun situations. Be careful if you start down this approach.

Comment: related: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html

Answer (score 3):

The need for friend is rare - generally it's when you need to reimplement some deep behaviour in one class without either rewriting it so that they both inherit from a single base or without providing lots of asccessors.

Only time I have needed it was to rewrite an openGL based renderer in ActiveX - when I needed to get at a lot of the low level model data, but couldn't (for non-technical reasons) reimplement a common ABC.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation recently, where i wanted to expose a few private member variables of class A to class B.

I didn't want to add public accessor functions because this would expose these members to all other classes.

I didn't want to make B a friend of A because this would expose all private members of A to B.

So i made another class (A-to-B private interface) solely for that purpose. It is a friend of A, and it has nothing except the accessor functions:

```
class A
{
    int top_secret; // only A has access to it
    int secret; // only A and B have access to it
    friend struct AToBInterface;
};

struct AToBInterface
{
    static int secret(const A& object) {return object.secret;}
};

class B
{
    void DoSecretStuff(A& object)
    {
        int secret = AToBInterface::secret(object);
        ...
    }
};
```

You can tweak syntax (e.g. if you need read-write access), it's just an idea. I use it in only one place in code, so no problem if syntax is a bit hairy.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, almost never.

"friend" often tends to be used to break encapsulation in that it can allow an external entity to access the private data of your class. You almost never want to do this - it is often better/safer to expose "semi-private" data via public accessors (that can check validity) than to expose private information to another class (which can tromp all over you).

However, sometimes you will have a pair/group of very closely related classes where it makes sense to keep them as separate classes, but they need low level access to data that really shouldn't be shared with the world at large. This is where 'friend' can be used - with care.

Generally, try to restrict the scope of friends (e.g. friend methods rather than friend classes) to minimise the areas where direct access to private data is allowed. Keep it as simple as possible - remember that another programmer reading your code might think "private" means data is truly private, and they could be tripped up by friends. Also, the more friends you use, the more tightly-coupled and hard to maintain your design will tend to be. They can be useful, but make sure you have good justification for each use.

Comment: `friend` breaks encapsulation almost in the same sense member-functions do!

Comment: Public accessors are dangerous, and can lock in implementation decisions.  If only one class needs to know the internals of another, you're probably better off using `friend`.  Friendship doesn't break encapsulation; it merely changes the shape of the capsule.

Comment: I agree with you all. However one can use "friend" well (i.e. in breaking one "logical entity" into several classes that have shared data) or badly (to make internal data accessible by random classes, which does break encapsulation, and is a nightmare to maintain). To make a member public, one should of course make it *safe* to access publicly, which is much better than making something a friend where often no such protections are added, because the programmer believes he knows what he is doing. Hence it is better to use "friend" very sparingly, *only where it is the right solution*.

Comment: (Wording of my first paragraph improved to reflect this)